# Authentication failed results in WSOD

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, wsod, laravel-validation

I'm using Larave 4.2, and everything works just fine. If I enter the correct credentials I will be taken to the correct URL (the one with auth filter). But the problem I'm currently experiencing is when one of the fields entered is incorrect and the user submits it will show a white screen.

I'm expecting of course that the user will be redirected back to login page with Input and display the error.

I've checked the filters, and quite sure it is still what came with Laravel and didn't change anything.

My routes

```
<?php

Route::get('login', function()
{
    // just a shortcut to redirec to /login into /cms/login : prevents redirect LOOP
    return Redirect::route('cms.login');
});

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'cms'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', function()
    {
        if (Auth::guest())
        {
            return Redirect::route('cms.login');
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::route('cms.home');
        }
    });

    Route::get('login', array(
        'as'   => 'cms.login',
        'uses' => 'CMSController@login'
    ));

    Route::post('login', array(
        'as'   => 'cms.postLogin',
        'uses' => 'CMSController@userLogin'
    ));

    Route::get('logout', array(
        'as'   => 'cms.logout',
        'uses' => 'CMSController@userLogout'
    ));

    Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
    {
        Route::get('home', array(
            'as'   => 'cms.home',
            'uses' => 'CMSController@home'
        ));

        Route::get('my-account', array(
            'as'   => 'cms.myaccount',
            'uses' => 'AccountsController@myAccount'
        ));

        Route::get('my-account/edit', array(
            'as'   => 'cms.edit-myaccount',
            'uses' => 'AccountsController@editMyAccount'
        ));

        Route::resource('accounts', 'AccountsController');
        Route::resource('products', 'ProductsController');
        Route::resource('news', 'NewsController');
        Route::resource('settings', 'SettingsController');
        Route::resource('homepage-sliders', 'HomepageSlidersController');
        Route::resource('testimonials', 'TestimonialsController');
        Route::resource('effects', 'EffectsController');
    });
});
```

User model

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * Fillable array
     *
     */
    protected $fillable = array('email', 'password', 'username', 'position', 'mobile');

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    /**
     * Sets the Validation Rules when Logging In
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $loginRules = array(
        'email'    => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|alpha_dash|min:6'
    );

    /**
     * Sets the Validation Rules creating a User
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $rules = array(
        'email'                 => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'username'              => 'required|min:2|unique:users',
        'position'              => 'required|',
        'mobile-number'         => 'required|numeric|digits:11',
        'password'              => 'required|alpha_dash|min:6|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required|alpha_dash|min:6'
    );

    /**
     * Sets the Validation Rules updating a User
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $updateRules = array(
        'username'              => 'required|min:2',
        'password'              => 'required|alpha_dash|min:6|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required|alpha_dash|min:6'
    );

    /**
     * Defines many-to-many relationship with Module
     *
     */
    public function permissions()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany('Module', 'permissions')->withPivot('add','edit', 'view','delete');
    }

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the Remember Token
     *
     * @return    string    $this->remember_token
     */
    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }

    /**
     * Set the Remember Token
     *
     * @param    string    $value
     */
    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Get the Remember Token name
     *
     * @return    string    'remember_token'
     */
    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return 'remember_token';
    }

    /**
     * Get the password and Hash it before saving to the database.
     *
     * @param     string    $value
     */
    public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
    }

    /**
     * Checks if Guest User input invalid credentials
     *
     * @param     array     $credentials
     * @return    object    $validation
     */
    public static function loginIsInvalid($credentials)
    {
        $validation = Validator::make($credentials, self::$loginRules);

        if ($validation->fails())
        {
            return $validation;
        }
    }
```

My CMSController

```
<?php

class CMSController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * Display the login page.
     * GET /cms
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function login()
    {
        return View::make('cms.login');
    }

    /**
     * Accepts the post request for login
     * of user in CMS
     *
     */
    public function userLogin()
    {
        $user_credentials['email']    = Input::get('email');
        $user_credentials['password'] = Input::get('password');

        //sets the remember_me variable
        if (Input::has('remember'))
        {
            $remember_me = true;
        }
        else
        {
            $remember_me = false;
        }

        if ($errors = User::loginIsInvalid($user_credentials))
        {
            return Redirect::route('cms.login')->withInput()->withErrors($errors);
        }

        if (Auth::attempt(array(
            'email'    => $user_credentials['email'],
            'password' => $user_credentials['password']), $remember_me))
        {
            return Redirect::route('cms.home');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Accepts the post request for logout
     * of user in CMS
     *
     */
    public function userLogout()
    {
        Session::clear();
        Auth::logout();

        return Redirect::route('cms.login');
    }

    /**
     * Directs user to home page
     *
     */
    public function home()
    {
        return View::make('cms.home');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently in your code there is nothing after `Auth::attempt()` - so if the Auth fails - it has no where to go.

Just add a return after the `Auth::attempt()` to make it work

```
    if (Auth::attempt(array(
        'email'    => $user_credentials['email'],
        'password' => $user_credentials['password']), $remember_me))
    {
        return Redirect::route('cms.home');
    }

    return Redirect::route('cms.login')->withInput()->withErrors($errors);
```